# CLIPS: Match multislot if all values match different other facts

Tags: matching, clips, expert-system

Is there any possibility to match each multislot in CLIPS to different other facts? I have a short example rule:

```
(stn-action (id ?id) (name lock-position) (state pending)
            (cond-actions) (opts ?r ?action ?to))
(stn-action (id ?other-id) (name lock-position) (state running|finished)
            (opts ?r ?action ?other-to&:~(eq ?other-to ?to)))
```

cond-actions is a multifield and I want each value to match against a fact that matches the second line. Obviously I need to match with member$, but I don't know how to match each member against a different fact in my fact-base. Is there any possibility to do this? A short set of complete facts that match would look like this:

```
(stn-action (id 3) (name lock-position) (state pending) (duration 0)
            (cond-actions 1 2) (opts R-1 PICK-CC C-CS2-I) (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000003))
(stn-action (id 2) (name lock-position) (state running) (duration 0)
            (cond-actions 1) (opts R-1 GET-PROD C-CS2-O) (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000002))
(stn-action (id 1) (name lock-position) (state finished) (duration 0)
            (cond-actions) (opts R-1 GET-PROD C-BS-O) (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000001))
```

My old solution was to remove id's from all fields upon action completion, but due to a different issue I cannot do this anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the forall conditional element:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate stn-action
   (slot id)
   (slot name)
   (slot state)
   (slot duration)
   (multislot cond-actions)
   (multislot opts)
   (slot active-robot)
   (slot sync-id))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   ;; id 3 will not match because PICK-CC doesn't match GET-PROD
   (stn-action (id 3) (name lock-position) (state pending) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions 1 2) (opts R-1 PICK-CC C-CS2-I) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000003))
   (stn-action (id 2) (name lock-position) (state running) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions 1) (opts R-1 GET-PROD C-CS2-O) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000002))
   (stn-action (id 1) (name lock-position) (state finished) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions) (opts R-1 GET-PROD C-BS-O) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000001))
   ;; id 6 will match
   (stn-action (id 6) (name lock-position) (state pending) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions 5 4) (opts R-1 PICK-CC C-CS2-I) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000003))
   (stn-action (id 5) (name lock-position) (state running) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions 4) (opts R-1 PICK-CC C-CS2-O) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000002))
   (stn-action (id 4) (name lock-position) (state finished) (duration 0)
               (cond-actions) (opts R-1 PICK-CC C-BS-O) 
               (active-robot R-1) (sync-id 1000001)))
CLIPS> 

(defrule match
   (stn-action (id ?id) 
               (name lock-position) 
               (state pending)
               (opts ?r ?action ?to))
   (forall (stn-action (id ?id) 
                       (cond-actions $? ?other-id $?))
           (stn-action (id ?other-id) 
                       (name lock-position) 
                       (state running | finished)
                       (opts ?r ?action ?other-to&~?to)))
   =>
   (printout t "id " ?id " has all cond-actions satisfied" crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
id 6 has all cond-actions satisfied
CLIPS>
```